# Signed pdf using timestamp itextSharp 5.x

Tags: java, itext

I need to add the ocsp, it looks like version 5.x and different from version 4.x

In version 4 asks to send a date in this new asks to send a byte type what data these would send

```
byte[] ocsp = null;
byte[] sh = signature.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hashByte, ocsp, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

I also need to add the TSAClientBouncyCastle, however I am using the option of preparing the pdf to subscribe later.

---

My signature class is next, I have a method where I prepare the file to be signed externally, are two services restm a client and a server.

I request to the server the hash of the file to be signed, I sign and return it to the server to add to the pdf.

I just do not know how to fill in with ocsp and tsclient

```
class PDFSigner {
    private List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate> chain = new List<Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate>();

    public void certificate(List<string> certificate)
    {
        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
        foreach (string cert in certificate)
        {
            this.chain.Add(cp.ReadCertificate(Convert.FromBase64String(cert)));
        }

    }

    public string prepared(string file)
    {
        try
        {

            FileStream signedPdf = new FileStream(file.Substring(0, file.Length - 4) + "_signed.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(file);
            PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, signedPdf, '\0');


            // Criar a assinatura aparente
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            appearance.Reason = "Because I can";
            appearance.Location = "My location";
            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(100, 100, 350, 150), reader.NumberOfPages, "Signature");
            appearance.SignatureGraphic = Image.GetInstance("C:\\signature.png");
            appearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION;
            appearance.Certificate = this.chain[0];            

            PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
            dic.Reason = appearance.Reason;
            dic.Location = appearance.Location;
            dic.Contact = appearance.Contact;
            dic.Date = new PdfDate(appearance.SignDate);
            appearance.CryptoDictionary = dic;
            Dictionary<PdfName, int> exc = new Dictionary<PdfName, int>();
            exc.Add(PdfName.CONTENTS, (int)(8192 * 2 + 2));
            appearance.PreClose(exc);
            PdfPKCS7 signature = new PdfPKCS7(null, this.chain, "SHA1", false);

            Stream data = appearance.GetRangeStream();
            byte[] hashByte = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, "SHA1");

            DateTime cal = DateTime.Now;
            byte[] ocsp = null;

            byte[] sh = signature.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hashByte, ocsp, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);

            string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashByte);
            string key = hash;

            if (Variable.appearance.ContainsKey(key))
                Variable.appearance.Remove(key);                

            if (Variable.signature.ContainsKey(key))
                Variable.signature.Remove(key);



            Variable.appearance.Add(key, appearance);
            Variable.signature.Add(key, signature);

            return hash;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new System.Exception(e.Message);
        }

    }

    public Contracts.File savePdf(Contracts.File file)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] signByte = Convert.FromBase64String(file.signature);

            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = Variable.appearance[file.hash];
            PdfPKCS7 signature = Variable.signature[file.hash];

            signature.SetExternalDigest(signByte, null, "RSA");
            byte[] encodedSig = signature.GetEncodedPKCS7();

            byte[] paddedSig = new byte[8192];
            Array.Copy(encodedSig, 0, paddedSig, 0, encodedSig.Length);
            PdfDictionary dic = new PdfDictionary();
            dic.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).SetHexWriting(true));

            appearance.Close(dic);

            Variable.appearance.Remove(file.hash);
            Variable.signature.Remove(file.hash);
            //verifySignature(file.name, "");

            return file;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new System.Exception(e.Message);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Need a help to populate the ocsp and add the TSAClientBouncyCastle

Comment: Do you want to add OCSP responses and a time stamp to the CMS signature container or separately as per PAdES part 4? Do you want to add OCSP responses only for the signer certificate or also for the whole chain (without anchor), or also for the time stamp authority certificate, and perhaps also for the OCSP signing certificates?